# Populating array using student class

Tags: c++

The question I'm trying to tackle is the following: Write a Student class which has fields: `name`, `ID`, `age`, `course` and member functions `getName()`, `getID()`, `getAge()` and `getCourse()`, which return values of the attributes. Create an array of Student and populate the array declared dynamically.

I thought I should try it myself but I'm very new to this here is what I got, it has a lot of errors I think this is because I'm a rookie. Would really appreciate the help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class student{
string name;
double ID;
int age;
string course;

public:
void setName(string sname);
void setID(double sID);
void setAge(int sage);
void setcourse(string scourse);

string getName();
double getID();
int getage();
string getcourse();
}

void student::setName(string sname){

name = sname;

}

void student::setID(double sID){

ID = sID;

}

void student::setAge(int sage){

age = sage;

}

void student::setcourse(string scourse){

course = scourse;
}

string student::getName(){

return name;
}

double student::getID(){

return ID;

}

int student::getage(){


return age;
}

string student::getcourse(){


return course;
}


void ReadData(student data[], int n);

int main() 
{
    student *record;
    int nItems;
    int i;


    cout << "How many students are there to process? : ";
    cin >> nItems;
    record = new student[nItems]; 
    ReadData(record, nItems);        

    for (i=0;i<nItems;i++)
        student i; 
        cout << record[i].name << "  " << record[i].ID << " " record[i].age << " " record[i].course << endl;
    return 0;
}

s


void ReadData(student data[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cout << "Enter a name : ";
        cin  >> data[i].name;
        cout << "Enter a ID as double : ";
        cin >> data[i].ID;
        cout << "Enter age as integer :"
        cin >> data[i].age;
        cout << "Enter course as string :";
        cin >> data[i].course;


    }
}
```

Comment: _"it has a lot of errors"_ So why didn't you quote those errors for readers to see? People need a defined problem to solve, not just a dump of code and a vague statement that it doesn't work.

Comment: _it has a lot of errors_ fix them. Learn. That's why you are doing homework.

Comment: Did you try _reading_ the errors? Since, typically, the errors tell, exactly, what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're not going to have a good time if your methodology for learning a language is trial and error, throwing code at a wall and hoping it eventually takes the correct shape... probably through people online fixing it for you! That's not a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Is the `s` after main actually in your code or was that some type of copy / paste error?

Comment: My advice is to not write so much code before hitting the compile button. That way you fix the problems as you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, classes in c++ end with ';', the definition of your class student misses ';'.

Besides the syntax error, I have 3 suggestions:

First, use const type &(universal reference which can't modify the referenced object) instead of pass-by-value for pass-by-value requires the argument to be copied and it's expensive for type such as string. This also applies to the return type of your functions get*

Second, your class student doesn't have any constructor. How do your initialize it?

Third, can you increase the degree the similarity the name of the member functions your defined? It's hard to

Your for loop should be enclosed with {}.

Since you set all the data members in your class in private, how can you access it outside a class without calling the defined member functions?(By default, any members followed class is private unless you write "public:")

Same errors occurs in function ReadData.

Between the definition of ReadData and main, there's a 's'.

I'd suggest you to use a operator overload function (which overload operator >>) instead of defining ReadData

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <cstdint>
template <std::size_t n>
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &in, student &stu[n]) {
    for (int i=0; i != n; ++i) {
        string Name, course;
        int age;
        double ID;
        in  >> Name >> ID >> age >> course;
        //If you have defined the constructor I told you above
       stu[i] = student(Name, ID, age, course);
       //The code below will actually have performance lose
       //if you don't enable compiler optimization, excspt in c++17
       //which such copy elision is mandatary
    }
    return in;
}
```